# Computer/robot like font

Tags: fonts, web-safe

What's a good web-safe font that looks like OCR-A or Westminster? I need a font that represents the way a robot might talk.

Comment: [Web safe fonts](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp) normally refers to standard fonts most people have installed on their computer.

Comment: Thanks my friend. I don't know much about fonting, so I wasn't sure what phrase to use. I needed a font that would likely be on my network but didn't need to be downloaded - I have zero internet access other than my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both on Google Fonts

VT323

[image: VT323]

Press Start 2P

[image: Press Start 2P]

You could always upload your own font for web.

Comment: Thanks so much. I can't really download any fonts right now, my only internet is via my phone for the next few months or so. Tethering is a no go too.